# SQL Server 2012 JOIN SELECT statement returns partitioning error

Tags: sql-server, join

I am writing a select statement in SQL Server 2012 based on the join of a column whose non-numerals are being used for the join.  what I'm expecting the query to do is strip out all non-numerals in both tables and perform joins based on the numeral values returned from the functions.

However I'm receiving this error:

> The maximum system-generated unique value for a duplicate group was
>   exceeded for index with partition ID 422228402503680. Dropping and
>   re-creating the index may resolve this; otherwise, use another
>   clustering key.

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO PP_MLS_BRIDGE
SELECT
      RTPropertyUniqueIdentifier
      ,[FA Unique Listing Identifier - Ref ID]
      ,MLS.[Listing Tracking ID]
      , MLS.[Assessor's Parcel Identification Number] as MLS_PARCELID
      , PP.ParcelID
      , GEOID
      ,'Parcel Match' as MatchType
      ,[Update Timestamp]
  FROM [property].[dbo].[MLS]
  join PROPERTY_PARAMETERS PP on [dbo].udf_extractInteger(PP.ParcelID) = [dbo].udf_extractInteger(MLS.[Assessor's Parcel Identification Number]);
```

Here is the dbo.udf_extractInteger() function:

```
USE [property]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[udf_extractInteger]    Script Date: 2/17/2017 7:04:29 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_extractInteger](@string VARCHAR(2000))
    RETURNS VARCHAR(2000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count int
    DECLARE @intNumbers VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @count = 0
    SET @intNumbers = ''

    WHILE @count <= LEN(@string)
    BEGIN
        IF SUBSTRING(@string, @count, 1)>='0' and SUBSTRING (@string, @count, 1) <='9'
            BEGIN
                SET @intNumbers = @intNumbers + SUBSTRING (@string, @count, 1)
            END
        SET @count = @count + 1
    END
    RETURN @intNumbers
END
```

Comment: I would check out [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/080bcb0f-ddb0-4a8a-ba1c-2f59e65eed00/sql-2012-the-maximum-systemgenerated-unique-value-for-a-duplicate-group-was-exceeded-for-index?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Comment: I wouldn't join on a function. Just for ha-ha's try to dump each table into a table variable or temp table with the extra join column computed by the function and join the temp tables together to see what you get.

Comment: @scsimon - Thanks.  My query plan is 100% on the insert.

Comment: @Jeremy, one table is 180M and the other is 35M records strong.  do you still stand by that mentality?

Comment: you should avoid joins with functions at all costs IMO. your query is clearly failing as is, and I feel the functions are to blame since SQL Server must try to process row by row in memory. another solution is to create another column, and update your table with the join field in a step before the query. after that as new records get inserted either have app logic calculate the field, or create a trigger to maintain the field.

Comment: also look into the native REPLACE function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx you can pass in a list of characters, and make the replace character an empty string.